# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field test.models.Aktion.id to test.models.Aktion

Tags: java, hibernate

my java ee application throws this exception and I cant figure out why:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of test.models.Aktion.id
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 118 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field test.models.Aktion.id to test.models.Aktion
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    ... 129 more
```

I cant figure out what this is.

What does it mean that it cant set the field there?

I dont even know what code to post here...

Thanks for tips and help!

Comment: `Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of test.models.Aktion.id`

Comment: here --> check this method .addAktion(test.models.Aktion)

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh what does that mean?

Comment: @IsabelHM: This method is:  public Aktion addAktion(Aktion aktion) {
  entityManager.persist(aktion);
  return aktion;
 }

Comment: Well... its your code... so you should know... All I can tell from this log is that... probably the model `Aktion` is missing a getter for field `id` and `hibernate` is not very happy about this. And by getter for field `id` ... I mean a function named `getId` which returns the field `id`.

Comment: Also... StackOverFlow is not a place to get your problems "solved"... its a place to get help in "solving your problem... yourself".

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh  Well, ive been trying that for hours and I just want it to work...

@ GeneratedValue
 @ Id
 private Long id;

 public Aktion() {
  konto = new Konto();
 }
 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

There are the getters and setters

Comment: I dont get it... I DO have getters and setters!! and the class is annotated with @Entitiy as well!

Answer (score 0):

So... soem part of your Aktion code is supposed to be like this,

```
@GeneratedValue
@Id
private Long id;

Konto knoto;

public Aktion() {
    konto = new Konto();
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

I think what you are missing is proper configuration for Hibernate... because somehow the getId() method is not returning any value... which means it was not initialized... which means hibernate did not get notified to generate this... or it does not know how to generate this.

My guess is - hibernate did not get notified to generate this. Which means you need to read a little more about using Hibernate.

I can not help with this without seeing the whole code... so please take a look at these tutorials - http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/

The problem probably lies in this file - test.services.AktionService or wherever you have done your bean configuration.

Hoping this helps.

Comment: Well, the thing is I am using JPA with hibernate, so all my annotations are from the javax.persistence package. Wouldnt I need to configure it all this way?

Comment: You will have to find out proper configuration for Hibernate + JPA... Also... If you are using something like Spring etc... then that will also change few things.

Comment: alright... looks like ive got to read a hundred articles again.... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

```
Konto konto;

public Aktion() {
   konto = new Konto();
}
```

It seems you have misspelled the object 'knoto' when you initialize it in the constructor Aktion().

Comment: please, fix your snippet, it looks quite bad formatted.